# angular 2 unit test for Output event emitter

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I am writing simple unit test case for Output Event Emitter :

describe('ConfirmDeclineComponent', () => {

```
    function findElement(fixture: ComponentFixture<ConfirmDeclineComponent>, selector: string): any {
    return fixture.debugElement.query(By.css(selector)).nativeElement;
}it('should emit on click back button', fakeAsync((): void => {

     let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ConfirmDeclineComponent);
     let instance: ConfirmDeclineComponent = fixture.componentInstance;
    spyOn(instance.submitConfirmInfoParent, 'emit');
    let button = findElement(fixture, '.back-btn')
     button.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
    fixture.detectChanges();
    tick();

    expect(comp.submitConfirmInfoParent.emit).toHaveBeenCalled();
}));});
```

### ConfirmDeclineComponent.ts :

```
    @Component({
selector: "decline",
templateUrl: "<button md-raised-button class="back-btn" color="accent" (click)="navigateToVinValidation()" style="margin-right:25px;padding:0px">
                <md-icon class="fa fa-arrow-left"></md-icon>
                {{'COMMON.BACK' | translate}}
            </button>"})`export class ConfirmDeclineComponent implements OnInit {
@Output() navigateToVinValidationParent = new EventEmitter();
ngOnInit() {}
navigateToVinValidation() {
    this.navigateToVinValidationParent.emit();
}}`
```

I am getting below error :

```
**Expected spy emit to have been called**
```

Comment: Are you spying into the right object. The emmiter is navigateToVinValidationParent and not submitConfirmInfoParent. Actually I can't see submitConfirmInfoParent anywhere. Can you post the the whole component?

Comment: Thanks , I did a silly mistake.